# The same indicators of the PAGE SPEED API

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I ran into a problem when getting data using the Google Page Speed API. I need to collect the metrics of a list of pages and for almost all pages except the first one from the list I get the same answers. It looks like these are aggregated metrics across the entire domain. Can you tell me what I need to do to give me the indicators of each individual page and why I am given the same data? I attach a screenshot with an example of the received data.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't is the answer, you do not have enough traffic to each individual page so it gives you the domain aggregate / average instead.

The best way to gather this information would be to use the [Google Web Vitals Library](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web-vitals) and pipe the results to your analytics / your own API.

You could try querying the [CrUX data](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-user-experience-report/) yourself (which is where the data comes from) but if you don't have enough traffic to the page you may not get meaningful results.

Comment: Thanks! Tell me, please, what traffic should be on the page, so that the data is taken for it, and not for the entire domain?